# In which direction is the surface the most steepest?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let be $f(x,y)=x^2+3y^2$ and the point is $A=(1,-2,13)$ Do I have to compute the direction derivative? I'm still unsure how does it work

Comment: You know that the gradient always points in the direction of the steepest slope ?

Comment: There's something wrong. Either $f$ should have three variables or the point has two coordinates.

Comment: @OpenBall it's fine as is, the "third variable" is $f(x, y)$.

Comment: This is the exact content of the exercise

Comment: So should I compute the partial derivatives First?

Comment: Yes. Compute $\nabla f$ and then plug $A$ in it !

Comment: @ElizabethHan alright - I see.

Comment: Yes, the gradient is a vector whose components are the partial derivatives. As Zubzub says, this will give you the direction in which the surface is steepest.

Comment: $f'_{x}= 2x+3y^2$ and $f'_{y}=3y^2$, if I calculated it correctly

Comment: Writing $f'$ only really makes sense for functions of a single variable (where there is no ambiguity about what we are differentiating with respect to). In your case, $f$ depends on $x$ and $y$ so we can write its partial derivatives as $f_x$ and $f_y$. In response to your last comment, Zaberkerl, you need to think more carefully about what you will obtain if you treat $y$ as 'fixed' in $f$ and differentiate with respect to $x$ when trying to find $f_x$.